# How to push notifications from server when app is killed

Tags: ios, notifications

I am working on an app, which is available to receive notifications from server. I used UILocalNotification, and my app can receive informations from server with foreground and background mode, but I don't know how my app can do it when it is killed by user. In fact, I know that Facebook message app can do it easily, we always receive notifications any time. Please, give me some solutions, thanks so much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899257/how-to-setup-push-notifications-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this link for all the steps which you have required to setup the push notification :
https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Comment: thank you, this link is useful for me. But when I read it, I also can not complete way how to send notifications to Apple Push Notification Sevices :((

Comment: You stuck anywhere?

Comment: ok, I found out the way to handle the trouble. I read this link and customize .php file there and I also create a server which manager all notifications I wanna send to app (when, what be send, how to send to android app and iOS app together...) :)) Moreover, someone also use Firebase library (Google cloud message) to do it. :))

Answer (score 1):

plz read this link

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

push notifications payload look like this

```
{
    "aps": {
         "badge": 10,
         "alert": "Hello world!",
         "sound": "Default"
    }
}
```

if you add message in alert. then your notification will show when your app in background or killed.

Comment: Thanks, push notification is a solution for this :)