# What are the equivalent of TCP Client and TCP Server for Swift

Tags: ios, sockets, tcp, swift3

Hi I am a newbie in iOS and Swift. I did some search on internet and i could not find a definite answer to my quest. I found socket.io but this is web socket.

Can you help and tell me the equivalent of TCP Client and TCP server for iOS for Swift 3.

I have these questions

If I use the iOS-base equivalent TCP client to send a message to server

1) On server-side, can I use other TCP Server to return message? any issue?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend to use Http request to send request to server and get a response from server, for more info check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift).And also to send data to client from server directly send a [push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899257/how-to-setup-push-notifications-in-swift) to client.

However look at this [link](https://github.com/vapor/socks) for tcp communication.